# Mysql Server stopped working

Tags: server, mysql

i tried  `sudo service mysql start` 
it gave me: "Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found".
and `/etc/init.d/mysql start` which gave me   "/etc/init.d/mysql: No such file or directory"
any help please ! i don't want to lose existing databases !!

Comment: 1) What does `systemctl status mysql.service` show? 2) What does `apt list mysql-server` show?

Comment: `systemctl status mysql.service` show 
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-09-17 21:11:29 UTC; 1 day 17h ago
 Main PID: 31942 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service   
`apt list mysql-server` shows 
mysql-server/xenial-updates,xenial-security 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 all
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it

Comment: It seems you don't have `mysql-server` installed. Perhaps you removed it by accident.

Comment: when i list mysql server it shows 
`mysql-server/xenial-updates,xenial-security 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 all`
`mysql-server/xenial 5.7.11-0ubuntu6 all`

Comment: Yes, and for me it shows a similar output but with the text `[installed]` appended. That is missing in your output.

Comment: then is there away to solve the problem without losing my databases ?